# Difference between ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy and <Model-name>::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Any one have any idea why i am getting a ModelName::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy result when i do a get all the children to a particular record?

It is causing a lot of issues as i am not able to get the desired element out of it in any ways.

i have a model nav_url and i am doing a recursive travel.

```
#resources is a collection of navUrl
def add_items resources
  items = Array.new

  resources.each do |r|
       if  r.nav_url.count == 0
         items << { :name =>  r.name , :link => r.link }
       else
         nav_urls = r.nav_url
         items << { :name =>  r.name , :link => r.link , :items => add_items(nav_urls)}
       end
     end

   items
 end
```

But i get a  NavUrl::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy for calling r.nav_url and it does not respond_to each.

I am having issues with depth 2.The above method is called by

```
resources = NavUrl.where(nav_url_id: nil)
add_items resources
```

Comment: what does resources.class give you?

Comment: @forthowin it gives me NavUrl::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy . Added some more info.

Comment: what does resources.class give you on the second pass?

Comment: Got the issue r.nav_url is giving me a new child of r :) thanks for help @forthowin